# Signup form with React and NodeJS - what is wrong with my axios request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, post, axios

I m trying to make a signup form with react and nodes bu Im getting a 404 back. I think he problem is in my react code. Any help or ideas would be very much appreciated! Thank you.

```
class Signup extends React.Component{
    constructor (props){
        super(props)
        this.state={
            email:'',
            password:''
        }
        this.handleClick=this.handleClick.bind(this)
        this.send=this.send.bind(this)
    }
    handleClick(elm){
        this.setState({
            [elm.target.name]: elm.target.value
        })
    }

    send(){
       event.preventDefault();
       const logindata={
        email:this.state.email,
        password:this.state.password
       }
       axios.post('/signup', logindata )
        .then(response=>response.data)

    }
    render(){

    return (
          <div>    
            <form>
               <input type="email" placeholder="Email" value={this.state.email} name="email" onChange={this.handleClick}/>
               <input type="password" placeholder="Password" value={this.state.password} name="password" onChange={this.handleClick}/>           
               <input onClick={this.send} type="submit"/>
            </form>
          </div>

        )
     }
}
```

backend nodes:

index.js

```
router.post('/signup', function(req,res,next){
   User.create(req.body)
    .then(function(user) {
      res.send(user)
    })
 }
```

Comment: With "getting a 404 back" means that you see a 404 on your page or in the console output? Because right now it looks like you redirect to another page which you might not want. What you need to do is having a `onSubmit` on your form and returning a `false` so it won't redirect.

Comment: yes its in the console output. Having onSubmit doesn't work either..still getting the same 404 error

Comment: createError.js?16d0:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404

Comment: The above makes it sound like your `User.create` method is failing.  Can you successfully see the data being passed to the back end with `console.log(req.body)`

Comment: no I can't, it never reaches the backend

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you're catching the onClick of the submit input (button), but you're not catching the onSubmit of the form.  If you replace the onClick of the input[type='submit'] to the be a onSubmit on the form, it should avoid an extra request that is likely giving you the 404.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things you need to add to your form and send function. Like tenor528 mentioned, your form needs to have an onSubmit handler attached to it and then remove the onClick on your input button. Then inside of your send() function, event isn't currently defined. Ensure you pass the event to the send function.

Something like the following:

```
send(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   const logindata={
    email:this.state.email,
    password:this.state.password
   }
   axios.post('/signup', logindata )
    .then(response=>response.data)

}


<form onSubmit={this.send}>
   <input type="email" placeholder="Email" value={this.state.email} name="email" onChange={this.handleClick}/>
   <input type="password" placeholder="Password" value={this.state.password} name="password" onChange={this.handleClick}/>           
   <input type="submit" value="Subimt" />
 </form>
```

Comment: Have you console logged the body on the server to make sure your getting the data expected? Or if your even getting inside...?

Comment: i can't console log anything because my backend route is never reached

Comment: I don't exactly know what that is but never needed that and don't think I need something like that to post data in my node express app

Answer (score 0):

I think that the script in the backend it's a little bit off, it should be router.route not router.post and yes you should require cors in your node server.
and when you post with axios you should put the link to the node server.